# Angular2 ngFor content not rendered on Safari

Tags: typescript, angular

I have a list of elements in an ngFor loop. When I refresh the page, only the first elements data is loaded. When I click an empty element the data suddenly pops up. This happens only when viewed in Safari. How can I get Safari to load all content?

[image]

```
<article *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index">
    <section class="item__content">
      <h3 class="item__name">
        <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>
      </h3>
      <p>
        {{item.description}}
      </p>
    </section>
</article>
```

Data comes from an API which's serves JSON.

Comment: Sounds like https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6889

Comment: Could be a Zone issue. Show how your data is retrieved.

Comment: A lot has happened to Angular2 lately, try updating til latest rc and also change your *ngFor="#item of list; #i = index" to *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index". The issue may have been solved for you already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error my problem was a |date pipe that was missing a specific format.

```
<time>{{topic.lastPostAt|date}}</time>
```

Changing it to this solved it for me:

```
<time>{{topic.lastPostAt|date:"MM/dd/yy"}}</time>
```

My example code on StackOverflow was missing this though. For some reason Safari was only able to render the content when a user event was triggered.

Comment: @SudipKafle Is it possible for you to create a plunkr so we can see it in action?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with angular 2 and Safari and solved it by adding the following library:

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

I added it before the other libraries.